# How to isolate emitted particles to a specific Curve Guide?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to get musical notes to guide along staff lines.

[image: emitted objects following curve guide]

If I have only one emitter and one curve guide they follow it perfectly.
Good Image above.

[image: emitted objects not following curve guides]

As soon as I add a second curve guide (baby step before adding it's emitter), the notes follow a curve, but its not either of the ones I've put in the scene!

Problem Image Above.

Image B1. Nearly edge on to see the emitted objects adhering to the curve guide:

[image]

Click  image above to see detail.

Image B2 and B3. After enabling the physics Force Field, Curve Guide, on the top ("F") line of the staff notice how the the previously working emitted particle system no longer follows the "B" line of the staff's Curve Guide:

There's nothing special about my Curve Guide settings other than having scaled down the Minimum Distance value with the intention of not having neighboring emitted particles be impacted by this Curve Guide. Curve Guide and Emitter Settings are above.

I've tried a few approaches to get around this, like separating the emitter/curve guide pairs across the Y axis from other pairs to give space between influence of the curve guide on unintended particles, or putting force fields above and below the treble clef to "squish" the particles into the middle.  Neither of those approaches worked.

I tried keyed emitters, and that works sort of, with its own problems that would rightly be a separate question here.

So is there a way to tie the emitted notes to a particular Curve Guide?  Or do I need to think about compositing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Try placing each curve with a force in a different group.
Then choose a different effector group for each particle system.

You can also consider a Follow Path constraint. Objects keyframes might well need a script for placement of hundreds or thousands.

Comment: That was quick and easy.  Maybe you can teach other people how to ask a question.  I give you question of the day award.