# Emit particles and move particle on this surface

Tags: particles

I'm new in blender, and I am stuck in the progress of my project.
I want to emit particles from an object (done). Then i need these particles move on the surface of this object randomly (turbulences).

I have duplicated my emitter object, and i scaled up a little (ALT+S). I put it in collider.
So now, my particles are stuck between these two objects, but the simulation time is big.

I just want to know if there are a better solution to lock moving particles on surface.

Thanks!
Best, Vincent.

Comment: Please show your current work in a screen capture.

Comment: Your wrote [particles move on the surface of this object randomly (turbulences)] .  [Randomly], in casual English, can mean many things ... 01. Small jitters, 02. Large Sweeping motions, 03. More 04. combinations of more unmentioned.   Please explain what (you) mean by Random.

Comment: Please show and explain your surface. You might be implying a closed surface ... or not.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We can't guess know how you set up your particles. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand your scene

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using Forces to direct the particles to your mesh surface. The key is to change the shape of the field to "Surface" :

[image: surface forcefield]

Here the cube has a Force Field added, with the type set to Force, Shape of 'Surface' and a **negative** strength. This will draw all affected particles towards the surface.

Note that particles aren't affected by forces applied to their own mesh - so you need to create a separate mesh to generate the particles. However, this could be in the same location as the mesh - so that it appears that the particles are spawned by the same mesh - if that is a requirement.

I also added a couple of fource fields to affect the particles - a 'Drag' field to slow them down (with Quandratic set to 2.0 to slow fast moving particles more than slow-moving ones) and a Turbulance field to move them about a bit. You could also add a Self Effect force on the particles themselves to push them gently away from each other. You'll need to play with the relative strengths of those forces for your situation but I used -5 for my 'surface' effect, 0.005 for the particle self-effect repulsion force, Linear 1.000 and Quadratic 2.000 for the Drag field and 7.4 for the Turbulence field to give them some 'jiggle'.

I also added Collision to the mesh so as to affect the particles when they do hit the surface - to effectively 'grab' them and slow them a bit - by increasing Stickiness to 0.7, Damping to 1.000 and Friction to 0.25.

This produces the following effect :

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please see this link

[How to isolate emitted particles to a specific Curve Guide?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/how-to-isolate-emitted-particles-to-a-specific-curve-guide/50820#50820)

And think about how you can customize the situation to meet your needs if possible.

An example might be one or more sweeping curves (nooodle soup teriyaki flavor) on the surface of your objects as a path for your particles.