# How can I make different particles follow many curves in same scene?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

How can I use 8 curves having *Force* and *Curve* in physics panel? Notice that *Curve Guide* is 4 time slower than *Force* and *Curve*.

[image: need for speed]

Comment: I am not sure if the question is about the speed of particles or about using multiple guides or something else.  Can you edit your question?

Comment: What is your priority in the situation above?  Particles following closely 8 different curve guides or something else?  Please state what is successful and what is not successful.  Do you have 2 concepts in your question or 1 concept?

Comment: the problem is to speed up or slow down particles along multiples curves

Answer (score 0):

- For slower particle speed change the lifetime value of the particle system to a larger value.
- For faster particle speed change the lifetime value of the particle system to a smaller value.
- The setting is in the particles settings emissions panel
- So the length of a curve and the lifetime combine to create speed
- The arrow in the Blender screen capture below shows the setting with an arrow

[image]

A previous answer regarding multiple Curve Guides ..

[How to isolate emitted particles to a specific Curve Guide?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50819/how-to-isolate-emitted-particles-to-a-specific-curve-guide/50820#50820)

---

I am addressing two different topics since I cannot tell how many different concept questions are in the Blender question above.