# Is there a way for particles on a curve guide to collide?

Tags: particles, meta-objects

[image: pic]

I have a Icosphere linked to a Metaball, which is following a curve guide, and I would like for the particles to fill up the box in the image you're seeing, instead of vanishing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To keep particles at the end of **Curve Guide** you can change *Settings* > **Free** to 0.300. But since particles Life Time is given to use this number of frames to get from start to end of curve (and has influence to its speed) it was quite confusing what is going on there.

[Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/forces/force_fields/types/curve_guide.html) says:

> **Free** – Fraction of particle life time, that is not used for the curve.

[image]

You can also try **Curve object** and under *Physics* enable *Force Field* > type *Curve*

[image]
One of many [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7_6lF7kmXs).

Use *Particles System > Physics* > **[Fluid](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/physics/particles/emitter/physics/fluid.html)** type to get volume in a pool.

Comment: Ok thank you - what if I create the particles on the curve guide "filling up" a box, and simultaneously have another sphere emit particles to create a mud-like substance just sitting there? That way the when the lifespan of the curve-guided particles end, the other blob of particles formed will already be there. However I will have to find a way so that the blob particles sitting/forming in the box aren't influenced by the curve guide. Would I just add another force field to stop that from happening?

Comment: Once (and if) that part is completed, I then have to create animation/illusion of the particles being sucked through hole in the box, so collision will have to be added, or maybe rigid body? That may have to be a separate post.

Comment: Force Field as effector limited to just some objects, sure use Collections. Here is answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50820/2214

Comment: Sorry for mistification, you can get what you need with particles when you switch physicss from Newtonian to Fluid. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOaQ9MPkdYg

Comment: Ok thanks - the files are no longer available, and when I switched from Newtonian to Fluid the particles went haywire on me.

Comment: Im not experienced with particle fluid setup, check some tutorials